# AttributeError: Everything was right from the tutorial video I used to make this, but still there is an error

Tags: python, attributeerror

I used a youtube video to make this platformer game. All of the attributes and parameters were defined, but still there appears an error. Here is my code block:

```
def update(self):
        # Game Loop Update
        self.all_sprites.update()

        # Check if player hits a platform only if falling
        if self.player.vel.y > 0:
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
            if hits:
                self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
                self.player.vel.y = 0

        # If player reaches top 1/4 of screen
        if self.player.rect.top <= HEIGHT / 4:
            self.player.pos.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
            for plat in self.platforms:
                plat.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
                if plat.rect.top >= HEIGHT:
                    plat.kill()
```

This is the Player Class for extra info:

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((30,40))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)
```

In the 6th line given in the code, the console gives error:
`AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'vel'`
Can anybody help?
Tell me if I need to provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, `self.player` contains a boolean value, not an object with a `vel` attribute as you expect.

The issue is not in the code you have provided. I suggest you review the surrounding code to ensure that this attribute is being handled properly.

Comment: This is the Player class                                                                                       `class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((30,40))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)
` @Brian

Comment: @Brocolimanx Please [edit] your question to provide any additional information or clarifications.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your help. I compared my code with the code given by the video and solved it.